# Sdk building, declare dependencies inside the assembly or use external?

Tags: c#, design, dependencies, microservices, sdk

At my company, we're building an SDK consisting of a number of assemblies. For example, we deliver an assembly called `Company.Platform.Security` that contains the implementation of our authorization model.

Now, this assembly contains code that talks to other services over HTTPS. It therefore needs to discover where those services live and needs to log the interactions and any errors that result from it.

So the same SDK, contains assemblies called `Company.Platform.Logging`, `Company.Platform.ServiceDiscovery` etc. These assemblies expose interfaces called `Company.Platform.Logging.ILogging` and `Company.Platform.ServiceDiscovery.IServiceDiscovery` respectively.

Now my question is, should the classes in `Company.Platform.Security` take these interfaces as dependencies in their constructors? Or should `Company.Platform.Security` define its own `Company.Platform.Security.Interfaces.ILogging` and `Company.Platform.Security.Interfaces.IServiceDiscovery` interface and take objects implementing those in the constructor of its classes?

The latter makes the assembly more cohesive IMO as it protects it against changes in those interfaces (which may or may not be maintained by other team members or teams). But a lot of concrete classes will just be very simple adapter classes for the classes in the other assemblies. It might also make the system more complex.

What are valid arguments for either approach?

Comment: Is it actually likely that, say, `Company.Platform.Logging.ILogging` will introduce a breaking change and you won't have to modify `Company.Platform.Security.Interfaces.ILogging` in response?

Comment: @svick Yes, `Company.Platform.Security.Interfaces.ILogging` represents how the `Company.Platform.Security` assembly uses logging. The concrete object implementing this may need to change due to the breaking change, but that is code outside the security assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the former approach. The latter duplicates a lot of effort, especially since the pairs of interfaces will likely be the same. So following the KISS and DRY principles, I would simply use one set of interfaces and not create a second (likely duplicate) set.

Comment: Okay, but then the next question would be whether all those interfaces should live together in an assembly (like `Company.Platform.Interfaces`) or in separate assemblies, possibly only containing the interface. Assume that each interface has multiple implementations based on different technology frameworks.

Comment: I would put these interfaces in a separate assembly that can be used by anyone needing a concrete implementation of the interface. Then you can use dependency injection to define and provide these implementations.